# Why isn't diagrams.sty compatible with LuaTeX

Tags: spacing, diagrams, luatex

I am trying to debug the problem with Paul Taylor's `diagrams.sty` (not in TeX Live or MiKTeX, but [available from CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/taylor)).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep=0pt
\tracingmacros=2\tracingcommands=2
\fbox{\begin{diagram}
a
\end{diagram}}
\tracingmacros=0\tracingcommands=0
\end{document}
```

The problem is that pdfTeX draws diagrams correct, but LuaTeX adds big vertical spaces. From macro level tracing shows that both engines does exactly the same.

Runing TL2012:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.70.2-2012080612 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX)    
(format=lualatex 2012.7.19)  19 JUN 2013 12:06  restricted \write18 enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
LuaTeX adaptation of babel <v3.8m-luatex-1.5> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, loaded.
(x:/texroot/texlive2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(x:/texroot/texlive2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
.... 
....
 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
 size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 diagrams.sty    2011/04/19 v3.94 Paul Taylor's commutative diagrams
```

Any hints?

Comment: I can't get the code to run at all: something up with `diagrams.sty`, I guess. Could you add `\listfiles` to your input and edit in the `*File list*` into the question. The 'banner' lines with pdfTeX and LuaTeX versions you are using (start of the `.log`) would also be handy.

Comment: The `diagrams` package uses various `\fontdimen` parameters and this might be the issue. Possibly a bug in LuaTeX, but it's almost impossible to trace it, because the code in `diagrams.sty` is obfuscated. Use another package for diagrams, for instance the more powerful `tikz-cd`.

Comment: Since he require that you send him copies of your work, I'd say it would be better to use *open* solutions instead.

Comment: Authors uses that package for diagrams and they use pdflatex. I can't tell them to use tikz. That happens not a first time :(

Comment: @Linuxss -- report the problem to paul taylor and ask him to solve it.  i believe his address is in the documentation.

Comment: I did it about a month ago, but he has a bad time now, so he didn't promised to fix it. That's why I wrote here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you wish to discuss this or other issues arising from my TeX code, please email me directly because I do not read TeX websites and am not willing to conduct discussions in public.

Thanks to Sean for his welcome, but without meaning to be patronising I did my TeX stuff before he was born and I don't want to join any new TeX "communities", even less to gain "reputation" (I have more than enough of that game on MathOverFlow).  As you can see from elsewhere on this page, TeX just caused me grief.  Probably many of the other early adopters have similar stories.  I maintained an off-the-shelf TeX system for Imperial College before texlive or any Linux package management systems existed and I was abused by the College management for doing so, eventually losing my job.

It would appear that there is a bug in LuaTeX (or a difference from Knuth's TeX) in that \par appears to generate an extra \baselineskip and \whatsit.

If someone intimately familiar with LuaTeX would like to contact me directly I can try to explain what I do with paragraphs within the diagrams package so that they can track this bug down.

For anyone who simply wants to use my package under LuaTeX the quick fix is this: after \usepackage{diagrams} add

```
% take this out when you update the diagrams package
\makeatletter
\let\oldCD@t\CD@t
\def\CD@t{\oldCD@t\baselineskip0pt\relax}
\makeatother
```

Please tell me privately whether this is successful.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Usually, answers are to be self-contained.  While it's very nice of you to offer help via email, this should rather be done as a comment when you [get enough reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges).  Thank you for all of your contributions to the TeX community.

Answer (score 4):

The version from

http://www.paultaylor.eu/diagrams/diagrams.sty

works without any error with lualatex on your example.

That version is now

```
\ProvidesPackage{diagrams}[2014/12/31 v3.94 Paul Taylor's commutative diagrams]
```

and produces the same output in luatex and pdftex.

Older answer below.

---

```
\ProvidesPackage{diagrams}[2011/04/19 v3.94 Paul Taylor's commutative diagrams]%%
```

pdflatex

[image]

lualatex

[image]

The observant will notice that these are not identical. Might be worth raising on the luatex list.

---

The luatex code seems to get a double box at the start of a pararaph which means that after `\setbox\z@\lastbox` doesn't clear the horizontal list and you get an extra blank para generated:

pdflatex

```
\CD@r ->\CD@GB \lastpenalty \unpenalty \ifnum \CD@GB >\z@ \setbox \z@ \lastbox 
\CD@lB 
{\count102}
{\unpenalty}
{\ifnum}
{false}
{\par}
{internal vertical mode: \unskip}
```

luatex

```
\CD@r ->\CD@GB \lastpenalty \unpenalty \ifnum \CD@GB >\z@ \setbox \z@ \lastbox 
\CD@lB 
{\count102}
{\unpenalty}
{\ifnum}
{false}
{\par}
@firstpass
[][]
@\par via @0 b=0 p=-10000 d=81000000
@@1: line 1.2- t=81000000 -> @0

{internal vertical mode: \unskip}
```

Comment: Do remember to read the copyright conditions in that package.

Comment: OK, that version at least compiles for me but I do see a difference in the output. Again, I think a list of versions would be very handy.

Comment: David, do you see difference in the output pdf using lualatex and pdflatex?

Comment: @josephwright what do you mean by “a list of versions”?  paul taylor has this neat idea that (pretty much) every compilation using his package should fail, first time.  i spent some time (on email) trying to talk him out of this, but he stood his ground.  afaik, he is no longer working on the package -- he’s not provided us with a new version for ages, but still we have this irritating trapdoor.  (similarly, i tried to persuade him to use a licence that would allow tl & miktex to hold the package, but no luck.)

Comment: @wasteofspace David says he gets no errors, but for me the PDF output looks different between pdfTeX and LuaTeX, as described in the question. So I'd like to check versions of the engines/other files to understand why that might be.

Comment: @davidcarlisle his error message says you can get the up-to-date version from his site or ctan.  but we're holding 2008/10/15 v3.93 ... ho hum.

Comment: @josephwright this is a loooong-established package, and it seems to use \specials -- i've not checked, but it could well be in the graphics generation.  if so, it's no surprise if luatex produces different results, surely?

Comment: @Linuxss should but see images added :(

Comment: @JosephWright using TL2013 (yay!) versions of pdflatex and lualtex the \tracingmacros output as in the MWE is identical, but the generated pdf is not,hmmm

Comment: tracing boxes shows this vertical skip, but I don't understand where it comes from. Package code is impossible to read :(