# Can't Install package using tlmgr

Tags: tlmgr

I don't know if I have some misunderstanding of how tlmgr works, but I can't get it to install packages.

I want to install this package [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/diagrams?lang=en), so I do

```
sudo tlmgr install diagrams
```

but I get

```
tlmgr install: package diagrams not present in repository.
```

I couldn't tell if this was because this was a collection, so I tried installing the more specific package inside it [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/taylor),using

```
 sudo tlmgr install taylor
```

but the same message appeared.

Comment: Indeed there is such package: `diagrams` is a collection of generic macro packages, which are individually available in TeX Live as well as MiKTeX. See this page on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/diagrams).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not all packages listed on that site are already included in TeX Live. You can install them manually, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73016/how-do-i-install-an-individual-package-on-a-linux-system

Comment: The `taylor` package is not in TeX Live - the package is a bit strange, the code is mostly (intentionally) obfusciated by the author, and there is a notion of a 'time bomb' which is a date after which the package does not run, and the author of the package is also not really community-minded (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176573). You can install the package manually if you want - but there are also other more modern packages with good documentation and many features available, such as `tikz-cd` (which is in TeX Live).

Comment: So is the reason it doesn't work is because tlmgr can only install packages that come with TexLive and can't install arbitrary CTAN packages?